# Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

While compiling the below code, I am getting warning:

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
>   maze->mazeValue = mazeValue;

This is the maze solving code. Have tried it but couldn't identify the issue. If I change 
 `char  mazeValue[BUFFERSIZE][BUFFERSIZE]` to `char \*\* mazeValue**`, the program gets compiled the did not execute. Windows throws alert.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE (1000)
#define MAZE_ENTRANCE '.'


struct maze {
    char ** mazeValue;
    int startx, starty;
    int numrows;
    int initdir;
};

void ReadMaze(struct maze * maze);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct maze maze;


    ReadMaze(&maze);
    printf("Thanks");
    //PrintStage(&maze);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


/*  Creates a maze from a file  */

void ReadMaze(struct maze * maze) {
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    char  mazeValue[BUFFERSIZE][BUFFERSIZE];
    //char workingMaze [BUFFERSIZE][BUFFERSIZE];
    //char ** map;
    int rows = 0, foundentrance = 0, foundexit = 0;
    int columns = 0, i = 0;

    /*  Determine number of rows in maze  */


    while ( fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) ){

       //puts(buffer);
       columns = strlen(buffer);

       /*
       for(i=0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
       {
            //printf("Row: %d\n", rows);
            //putchar(buffer[i]);
            //printf("\n");
            mazeValue[rows][i] = buffer[i];
            //putchar(mazeValue[rows][i]);
            //printf("\n");
       }
       */

       strcpy(mazeValue[rows], buffer);

       for ( i = strlen(mazeValue[rows]) - 1; isspace(mazeValue[rows][i]); --i )
            mazeValue[rows][i] = 0;

        /*  Check for entrance and save the location if it finds  */

        if ( !foundentrance && rows == 0) {
            i = 0;

            printf("rows %d\n", rows );
            printf("i %d\n", i );

            while ( mazeValue[rows][i] != MAZE_ENTRANCE && mazeValue[rows][i++] ){

                if ( mazeValue[rows][i] == MAZE_ENTRANCE ) {
                    maze->startx = i;
                    maze->starty = rows;
                    foundentrance = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        ++rows;
    }

    maze->mazeValue = mazeValue;
    maze->numrows = rows;

    printf("maze->startx %d\n", maze->startx);
    printf("maze->starty %d\n", maze->starty );

    printf("\n");
    printf("Stage 1\n");
    printf("=======\n");
    printf("maze has %d rows and %d columns\n\n", rows, columns);

    i=0;
    int j;

    for(i=0; i<=rows; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=columns; ++j){
            printf("%c", mazeValue[i][j]);
            printf("%c", mazeValue[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("foundentrance: %d\n", foundentrance);

}
```

Comment: Why now a days we're seeing so much `maze solving code` issues? Is it part of some sort of assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Even if the assignment worked, you can't do that. You're trying to store a local array, and use it later, which is not permitted and will give you undefined behavior.

You need to heap-allocate (using `malloc()`) the data inside the structure, not use a local array.

First change the structure member to be a plain character pointer:

```
char *mazeValue;  /* Single-star! */
```

Then allocate it like:

```
maze->mazeValue = malloc(BUFFERSIZE * BUFFERSIZE);
```

Then do the 2D-indexing yourself, it's much easier:

```
maze->mazeValue[y * BUFFERSIZE + x] = '?';
```

Of course `x` and `y` must both be between `0` and `BUFFERSIZE - 1`.

Note: if you really want `BUFFERSIZE` to be constant, you can instead declare the array directly in the structure, going back to a 2D-array:

```
char mazeValue[BUFFERSIZE][BUFFERSIZE];
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointers are of different types. The `mazevalue` in the struct is a pointer to a pointer.

The `mazevalue` in the `ReadMaze` function is a 2D array. A pointer to a 2D array has a type of pointer to array and is declared like this int `(*mazevalue)[BUFFERSIZE]`.

However, changing the pointer in the struct will not solve your problem. The `mazevalue` in `ReadMaze` is a local variable and can be overwritten when the function exits. The value in the structure may be overwritten in this case.

The best option would be to keep the struct the same, and change the `ReadMaze` function. In this you should have `mazevalue` as a pointer to pointer. Then you can `malloc` a 2D array as required.

e.g.

```
void ReadMaze(struct maze * maze) {
   char  **mazeValue;

   mazevalue = malloc(BUFFERSIZE * sizeof(char*));
   for (i=0; i<BUFFERSIZE; i++)
   {
      mazevalue[i] = malloc(BUFFERSIZE);
   }
   // Other code below...

}
```

You can also optimize and allocate only the required no of rows and columns required for the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After implementing above code, now it's not giving any error. But while printing maze, it is printing few junk characters. <br/> 
──  ;;  pp→→;;